# Connect JIRA and retrieve Information

Tags: java, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I have a Task that is to retrieve some Information from a JIRA account through Java. I downloaded the Jira API which is working with Java, but I have no idea how to make it work. I have to pass somewhere my username and password for log in and after that to retrieve what Information I want from what project I want.

```
JiraRestClientFactory factory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
URI uri = new URI(JIRA_URL);
JiraRestClient client = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(uri,  JIRA_ADMIN_USERNAME, JIRA_ADMIN_PASSWORD);

// Invoke the JRJC Client
Promise<User> promise = client.getUserClient().getUser("admin");


// Here I am getting the error!!
User user = promise.claim();
///////////////////////////////////////

// Print the result
System.out.println(String.format("Your admin user's email address is: %s\r\n", user.getEmailAddress()));

// Done
System.out.println("Example complete. Now exiting.");
System.exit(0);
```

That above code is not working, because either if I pass a wrong password and a wrong username is showing me the same result. I have to know how to connect properly to JIRA and retrive some Information in JSON from there! Thank you for your time!

Here is the error

```
Caused by: com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.RestClientException: org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 9 of
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't have the necessary permission to acces Jira , you have to connect with jira with an account that have the correct permissions!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that you are sending incorrect creds. Try using the email address instead of just "admin".

Here is some code that might help: https://github.com/somaiah/jrjc

I check for an issue, but getting user info would be similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code the get the results.Remember I am using this in my gradle project where I am downloading all the dependencies of JRCJ

```
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.JiraRestClientFactory
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.User
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory
import com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promise

/**
 * TODO: Class description
 *
 * on 20 Jul 2017
 */
class Jira {
  private static final String JIRA_URL = "https://JIRA.test.com"
  private static final String JIRA_ADMIN_USERNAME = "ABCDE"
  private static final String JIRA_ADMIN_PASSWORD = "******"

  static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    // Construct the JRJC client
    System.out.println(String.format("Logging in to %s with username '%s' and password '%s'", JIRA_URL, JIRA_ADMIN_USERNAME, JIRA_ADMIN_PASSWORD))
    JiraRestClientFactory factory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory()
    URI uri = new URI(JIRA_URL)
    JiraRestClient client = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(uri, JIRA_ADMIN_USERNAME, JIRA_ADMIN_PASSWORD)


    // Invoke the JRJC Client
    Promise<User> promise = client.getUserClient().getUser(JIRA_ADMIN_USERNAME)
    User user = promise.claim()

    // Print the result
    System.out.println(String.format("Your user's email address is: %s\r\n", user.getEmailAddress()))

    // Done
    //System.out.println("Example complete. Now exiting.")
    //System.exit(0)
  }
}
```